# Three20: Change the CGSize of a Thumbnail?

Tags: size, thumbnails, three20

I was wondering if there is a way to set the size of the Thumbnails in in the TTPhotoViewController from the three20 framework? So far I found out, the images need to be 75x75 px while I'd like them to be more of a rectangular shape i.e. 60x75 px....

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I dug deeper into the framework and eventually found the responsible class for it. Will do that earlier next time.....

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236599/how-to-change-the-size-of-the-grid-of-ttthumbsviewcontroller) Says which classes to extend and methods to override.