# How to change the size of the grid of TTThumbsViewController

Tags: iphone, three20, photo-gallery, ttthumbsviewcontroller

I'm using the Three20 Photo Gallery and wondered if it's possible to have two different grid sizes in two different galleries. So in Gallery one I use the standard size (up to 4x4 thumbs) and in the other I only want a 2x2 gallery size. Is that possible and if yes how (I suppose subclassing comes into play)? I would really appreciate some code samples. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I did the same thing and my solution was like this

1, Extend TTThumbsDataSource  and override

- (NSInteger)columnCount {
  //  CGFloat width = TTScreenBounds().size.width;
  //  return round((width - kThumbSpacing*2) / (kThumbSize+kThumbSpacing));
  return 3;
  }
- (Class)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellClassForObject:(id)object {
  if ([object conformsToProtocol:@protocol(TTPhoto)]) {
      return [TTThumbsTableViewCell_Ext class];
  } else {
      return [super tableView:tableView cellClassForObject:object];
  }
  }

2, Extend TTThumbsTableViewCell and change the setting

_thumbSize = 95 (your calculated size) in

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString*)identifier